# Magento jQuery / Prototype Issues in 1.9 After upgrade

Tags: jquery, magento, prototype, magento-1.9

After doing an upgrade from 1.3 ( and only moving theme and a couple of extensions  - so reasonably clean install)  , I am having a lot of jquery issues and prototype issues. For example home page: Class is not defined , Ajax is not defined.

I'm not sure where to start looking as it looks like a LOT of errors although I can do a few things ok on the site just not many ajax type functions.

even the js/varien/js.js  file says $ is not a function.

help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like jQuery and or prototype lib is missing or conflicting on your install.

In your theme, you have to make sur that those 3 lines appear in first in the block of name **head** under the node `<default>` on the file `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/page.xml` and in that exact order.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
```

For your information a fresh installed `page.xml` stripped to those lines would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And you also have to check that those 3 files exists on your server

```
js/prototype/prototype.js
js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js
```

If not, get them from a fresh copy of Magento.